# Laravel 5.5 Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOPgSql\Driver' not found

Tags: php, migration, laravel-5.5

I am working in laravel 5.5 with postgras 9.6, I manage to run all migration and rollback, but when I want to run migration for rename a column in Table i get the  `Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOPgSql\Driver' not found` error, hire is migration file:

```
class CreateRenameApplicantIdInBillToApplicationId extends Migration
```

{

```
public function up()
{

    Schema::table('bill_bills', function($table) {
        $table->renameColumn('applicant_id', 'application_id');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('bill_bills', function($table) {
        $table->renameColumn('applicantion_id', 'applicant_id');
    });
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#renaming-columns] this is the reference for renaming column in existing table I used

Answer (score 14):

To renaming columns **Laravel 5.x**, you need to require **doctrine/dbal** package in your **composer.json** file.

`composer require doctrine/dbal`

I think this will help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For PHP 7 in Linux you can install driver via

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-pgsql`